# How can I detect if all elements are removed from my div?

Tags: jquery

I want to add some div boxes by clicking on `add`. Then I want to be able to remove those boxes again by clicking on the remove button. When all boxes are removed from `list` then I want to have an alert note. There is a mistake in my function and I cannot figure it out:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $( ".add" ).click(function() {
       var el = $('<div class="box">box to remove<button class="remove">remove</button></div>');
       $(".list").append(el);
   });

   $('.remove').on('click', '.remove', function () {
        $(this).closest(".box").remove();

        if ($(this).children().length < 0) {
            alert("all removed");
        }
    }); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="add" style="cursor:pointer">add</div>
<div class="list"></div>
```

Comment: When there are no elements in the `div`, the length of it's children will be exactly **0**. You're checking to see if it's *less than 0*, and so that case will never hit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  
 $( ".add" ).click(function() {
 var el = $('<div class="box">box to remove<button class="remove">remove</button></div>');
  $(".list").append(el);
   
   });
   $(document).on('click', '.remove',function () {
      $(this).parent().remove();
      if(!$('.remove').length) alert('All removed');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="add" style="cursor:pointer">add</div>
<div class="list"></div>
```

Comment: Care to explain please.

Answer (score 2):

1. You should use event delegation `on()` since your div's are added dynamically to the DOM :

   ```
   $('body').on('click', '.remove', function () {
       //Your code
   });
   ```
2. The following condition will never be achieved since when there's no div's the length will be `0` but never something lower than zero :

   ```
   if ($(this).children().length < 0) {
   ```

   Should be `== 0` :

   ```
   if ($('.remove').length == 0) {
   ```

Hope this helps.

```js
$(function() {

  $( ".add" ).click(function() {
    var el = $('<div class="box">box to remove<button class="remove">remove</button></div>');
    $(".list").append(el);
  });

  $('body').on('click', '.remove', function () {
    $(this).closest(".box").remove();
    
    if ( $('.remove').length == 0) {
      alert("all removed");
    }
  });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="add" style="cursor:pointer">add</div>
<div class="list"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that length can't be < 0. The lowest value is 0.

Try this?

```
$('.remove').on('click', function () {
  $('.list').html('');

  if ($(this).children().length === 0) {
    alert("all removed");
  }
});
```

Comment: `$('.remove').on('click', function () {` will not work since the `.remove` elements are added dynamically to page..